# PowerApps Get Selected Item from Lookup to make a Button Visible at the Command line bar

Tags: command-line, lookup, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I want a button from the command line bar to be visible or invisible depending on whether a record has been selected in the lookup field from the main form or not.
If no record has been selected, then the button should be displayed. Otherwise not.
For this problem, I want to use the Power Fx in PowerApps, but I haven't found a command yet, which shows me the content or something like that of the lookup field. Other field data types like text have worked without problems.
With Javascript, I already managed it without problems, but I would like to do it also in PowerFx if that should work.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqDJ6.png

The records come from the Table Company, where the attribute is Companyname.

Commands where I think they might work:

`If([Selected Record];true;false)`;`If(IsBlank([Selected Record]);true;false)`;`If(IsBlankOrError([Selected Record]);true;false)`;`If(IsEmpty([Selected Record]);true;false)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are 2 scenarios:

1. The Lookup form control element is a Dropdown with a Selected output property. Then your approach would work like If(IsBlankOrError(DataCardValue1.Selected),true,false)
2. If your form control element is a ComboBox then you could use If(CountRows(DataCardValue1.SelectedItems)>0,true,false) or the above described IsBlankOrError.